# Can i drag and drop list item to text box in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

I have requirement i..e, I have SelectManyMenu and i want drag list item into dropped to text box or text area in JSF?. Is there any possible?

Comment: take a look at the various DragDrop options of Primefaces in here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf - look in the DragDrop section

Answer (score -1):

I would try a combination of the selectManyMenu JavaScript API and JavaScript (jQuery UI has drag and drop support).
Have a look at the documentation of the component here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/